# Consequence of Los' theorem

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, model-theory

> Let $D$ be a free ultrafilter on $\omega$ and let $\underline{M}$ be the structure $(\mathbb N,+,\times,<,0,1)$. Then for the element $u=[(1,2,3,\ldots,)]\in \underline{M}^\omega/ D$, we have
> $$\underline{M} \models 1+\ldots +1<u.$$

Can someone explain me what the above statement means? Apparently it is an illustration to differentiate between $\underline{M}$ and $\underline{M}^\omega/ D$ but I don't see what that means? I also don't see what is the role of the *free* ultrafiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

1.There is a canonical way to define the relation $<$ on the ultraproduct: $[((a_i))]<[((b_i))]$ iff $a_i<b_i$ a.s. It satisfies all properties of the linear order. It is also standard to define $+$ and $\cdot$ on the ultraproduct.

2. $\mathbb N$ embeds into the ultraproduct naturally: $n\mapsto [((n))]$, so we can identify $[((n))]$ with number $n$. Then in the ultraproduct $1+1+...+1$ ($n$ times) is equal to $n$.
3. According to the definition of $<$, we have that for every natural $n$, $n<[(1,2,3,...)]$.
4. The last property does not hold if the ultrafilter is not free in your terminology.

Comment: Doesn't $n<[(1,2,3,\ldots)]$ then mean that $n<1$, $n<2$, $n<3, \ldots$ which is not true?

Comment: Also, what is a.s.?

Comment: a.s. means "almost surely", that is the set of indices for which it is true is an element of the ultrafilter. There is a standard way to treat an ultrafilter as a measure on $\omega$, which has two values, $0,1$, hence the measure theoretic terminology.

Comment: By definition $n<[(1,2,...)]$ because $n<m$ for all but finitely many natural numbers $m$ and every  set of natural numbers which contains all natural number except a finite collection of numbers is in the ultrafilter (since the ultrafilter is free).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: By the way, Łoś's theorem is very indirectly related to this.

Comment: "almost everywhere", or "a.e.", is how one usually says it in English.

Comment: @BrianO: Yes, you are right! My mistake.

Comment: @markvs But your term makes sense – same idea, from a probability point of view. Also used: “for almost all”.

Comment: @BrianO: almost all = a.a.

Comment: @markvs Why doesn't it contradict Los' theorem?

Comment: Results are both true and do not contradict each other. The Łoś's theorem is used here to prove that $<$ is an order. But it is easy to prove directly.

Comment: @markvs Since the ultrafilter is free, it contains the Frechet filter, hence complement of finite sets, this is why $n<m$ for all but finitely many, correct?

Comment: Correct.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $\overline{n}$ to be the term $1 + \ldots + 1$ where $1$ occurs $n$ times.

In other words, $\overline{0} = 0$ and $\overline{S(n)} = \overline{n} + 1$.

Then for all $n$, $\underline{M}^\omega / D \models \overline{n} < u$.

Proof: in particular, in the structure $\underline{M} ^ \omega / D$, the term $\overline{n}$ evaluates to $[(n, n, \ldots)]$. Take some element $J \in D$ such that $\forall j \in J, n < j$. This is possible because $D$ is free. We see that for all $n < j$, we have $n < j$ and in particular $(n, n, \ldots)_j = n < j + 1 = (1, 2, \ldots)_j$. Therefore, $\overline{n} < u$.

Comment: What is $(n,n,\ldots,)_j$?

Comment: @modeltheory In general, $a_j$ refers to the $j$th element of the sequence $a$.

Comment: Then isn't $(1,2,\ldots)_j=j$?

Comment: @modeltheory No, because clearly $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ in this context, so our indices are $0$-indexed and not $1$-indexed.